# PTC Windchill WRS API Can't add attributes to WTParts on creation

Tags: python, api, rest, cad, ptc-windchill

How can I add data to our custom attributes via the WRS API? We have an attribute for WTParts called "CAT_CODE" and I want to add data to it via the CreatePart command (`http://##.###.#.###:##/Windchill/servlet/odata/v5/ProdMgmt/Parts`). My data is:

```
{
    "DefaultUnit":{},
    "EndItem":False,
    "GatheringPart":False,
    "DefaultTraceCode":{},
    "PhantomManufacturingPart":False,
    "ConfigurableModule":{},
    "Name":"pyapitest",
    "Source":{},
    "AssemblyMode":{},
    "Uses@odata.bind":[],
    "DescribedBy@odata.bind":[],
    "References@odata.bind":[],
    "PartDocAssociations@odata.bind":[],
    "Context@odata.bind":"Containers('OR:wt.pdmlink.PDMLinkProduct:109352')",
    "Folder@odata.bind":"Containers('OR:wt.folder.SubFolder:155247')",
    "CAT_CODE": "52",
}
```

The error code I get when running the POST command is `{"error":{"code":null,"message":"'CAT_CODE' can not be mapped as a property or an annotation."}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the underscore in `CAT_CODE` is not passed into the IBA attribute. So deleting the underscore fixed it. The correct data is

```
{
    "DefaultUnit":{},
    "EndItem":False,
    "GatheringPart":False,
    "DefaultTraceCode":{},
    "PhantomManufacturingPart":False,
    "ConfigurableModule":{},
    "Name":"pyapitest",
    "Source":{},
    "AssemblyMode":{},
    "Uses@odata.bind":[],
    "DescribedBy@odata.bind":[],
    "References@odata.bind":[],
    "PartDocAssociations@odata.bind":[],
    "CATCODE":"520000",
    "Context@odata.bind":"Containers('OR:wt.inf.library.WTLibrary:110138')",
    "Folder@odata.bind":"Folders('OR:wt.folder.SubFolder:155247')",
}
```

Also, I noticed an issue with the `Folder@odata.bind` path which was malformed.